# How do I debug a rake application in Eclipse?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, eclipse, debugging

I run some ruby tests using the following command in commandline:

```
rake tests:integration:core:test_code parameters here
```

test_code is actually test_code.rb, but I don't need to put .rb in the above command. To debug this in commandline, I simply add `-r debug` after rake in the above command. I want 
to be able to debug this using GUI of eclipse. How do I do it ? I am using the DLTK ruby plugin.

I tried this - eclipse > run > debug configurations. Then i tried both debug as Remote ruby application and ruby script. For both the options, in the main tab of debug configs, I could not see the project which contains my ruby test. I can see other ruby projects though. In fact this project does not even have a ruby symbol on it.

Comment: Never used this plugin before, but a lot of Eclipse plugins have an option to change the command that it runs. You might be able to find that in the configuration screen.

Comment: @Jon - In which option of the IDE can i find it ? I guess tab Agruments > Interpreter arguments. Is that correct ?

Comment: Like I said, I've never used the plugin, so I wouldn't know. If you see a text field labeled `command` that starts with `rake`, it's probably the right one.

Comment: @Jon - The problem is that the plugin/eclipse does not even recognize my project as a ruby project. I know this because there is no ruby photo above the project (which was downloaded from a source). The ruby is there on projects which I made myself.

Comment: @Jon - I made a related question here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25861312/eclipse-how-do-i-convert-a-general-project-to-ruby-project