# Eclipse - How do I convert a general project to ruby project?

Tags: ruby, eclipse

I use eclipse kepler and the ruby DLTK plugin. From a similar answer, I learned that one can use `project > properties > project facets > Convert to faceted form`, to convert a project from general to a specific type. In my list of project facets, there are only java ee options and no ruby options.

I could also try to mess with project config files as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179439/how-to-change-an-eclipse-default-project-into-a-java-project). But, the commentators advise against doing it.

How do I proceed ?

Comment: I don't know if the Ruby plugin uses facets, I suspect not. Is there something in the project context menu, such as "Add Ruby nature"? Or if you create a new Ruby project, can you select an existing project in the wizard?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any way of doing it through the Project properties.

Add the following XML stanzas to your .project file;

```
<buildSpec>
    <buildCommand>
        <name>org.eclipse.dltk.core.scriptbuilder</name>
        <arguments>
        </arguments>
    </buildCommand>
</buildSpec>
<natures>
    <nature>org.eclipse.dltk.ruby.core.nature</nature>
</natures>
```

Comment: Use Paul's stanza answer and also add a .buildpath file with the following content so the interpreter is added too:
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <buildpath>
        <buildpathentry kind="src" path=""/>
        <buildpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.dltk.launching.INTERPRETER_CONTAINER"/>
    </buildpath>

Answer (score -2):

Usually use ruby like a script with just a `xx.rb` file, or use with some frameworks like `Ruby on Rails` or other else. If you want to do something with ruby to complete some little function just make a `rb` field is ok.